# How do I compile my main Java program on the command line when it includes an external java package?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, java-package

I'm a relative Java newbie so apologies if the question appears somewhat basic. I've googled high and low for an answer here and I'm not finding anything that's helping.

Problem:

Whilst I'm able to integrate external packages into my Java programs from an IDE environment, I am trying to do run a very basic program from the command line that calls on a separate, basic package file that I have written - and am simply doing all this as I want to have a bottom-up understanding of how package files are related to a main program by Java.

I have a program that sits on my desktop named MyProgram.java:

```
import org.somepackage;

public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {

    System.out.println("Programme up and running...");
    Human myHuman = new Human(); 
    myHuman.scream();

  }
```

Still on the Desktop, I then have another folder which I've named *src*, inside of which I have created the necessary subfolders corresponding to the package name, i.e. *./src/org/somepackage* - and in this location, I have the Human.java file which defines the Human class with the following contents:

```
package org.somepackage;

public class Human {

    public void scream() {

    System.out.println("I exist!!");

  }

}
```

I then created a classes folder, again on the Desktop, and ran the following compile command on the command line:

```
javac -d ./classes/ ./src/org/packagename/Human.java
```

This ran fine and created - as expected - the Human.class file within the ./classes/org/packagename/ location.

However, where I fall down is when I then try to compile MyProgram.java on the command line, i.e.

```
javac -cp ".:./classes/" MyProgram.java
```

As you'll see, my class path contains a reference to the current location (*"."*) for the MyProgram.java file, and it contains a reference to the classes folder (*"./classes/"*) which is the base location for the org.somepackage package inside whose subfolders (*./classes/org/somepackage/*) on can find the *Human.class* file.

At this stage, I was simply expecting the java engine to compile *MyProgram.java* into the program MyProgram.class - but, instead, I get an error:

*MyProgram.java:1: error: package org does not exist*

I've been following the instructions listed here:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html

and I don't appear to be deviating from the instructions - yet I'm unable to locate an explanation on Stackoverflow or anywhere else as to a  possible reason for this compile failure. If anyone has an idea, your help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
import org.somepackage; <--

public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {

    System.out.println("Programme up and running...");
    Human myHuman = new Human(); 
    myHuman.scream();

  }
```

you forgot to import class actually, you need to write this name 
`import org.somepackage.Human;` import all package content `import org.somepackage.*;` or write full qualified name of class in your code

```
org.somepackage.Human myHuman = new org.somepackage.Human(); 
myHuman.scream();
```

correct mistake:

```
import org.somepackage.Human;

public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {

    System.out.println("Programme up and running...");
    Human myHuman = new Human(); 
    myHuman.scream();

  }
```

after that compile your Human.java by this command:

```
javac -d classes Human.java
```

and MyProgram.java

```
javac -d classes -cp "classes" MyProgram.java
```

and run MyProgram by

```
java -cp "classes" MyProgram
```

Comment: My first post on stackoverflow, and barely a few minutes after submitting the question, I get the solution to my problem - thank you so much! Code is working a treat now....

Comment: @GoingMush Good question contains half of the answer. When all your code works, mark answer as accepted according to site rules.